# Container with unique pointer to an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns, polymorphism, abstract-class

I've been trying to create a factory method which allocates subclasses entities from a given abstract class, which I'll name `Shape` for simplicity. It looks something like this:

```
Shape* makeChild(Type type) const
{
     switch(type)
    {
        case QUAD:
            return new Quad();
        case RECTANGLE:
            return new Rectangle();
        case TRIANGLE:
            return new Triangle();
        default:
            return new Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to keep these entities inside a structure, and I understand I need to allocate `Shape*` entities, but I would like for the objects to be automatically managed by using `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` instead.
My `ShapeTree` struct looks something like this:

```
struct ShapeTree {
    int index_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes_;

    void add(Shape* shape) {shapes_.push_back(std::make_unique<Shape>(shape));}
    void removeLast(){shapes_.pop_back();}

    ShapeTree(const int index) : index_{index}{}
    ShapeTree(const int index, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>& shapes) : index_{index}, shapes_{std::move(shapes)}{}};
```

Compiler complains about having Shape default copy constructor being marked as deleted, I understand this is the case since I have a unique pointer and I can't copy it, but deleting the copy constructor and assignment and using the default move constructor and assignment won't work either. It also complains that no instances of `Shape` can be created as it is abstract, even thought I am only returning subclasses.

A different version of the same structure works completely fine when using raw pointers. E.g.

```
struct ShapeTree {
    int index_;
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes_;

    void add(Shape* shape) {shapes_.push_back(shape);}
    void removeLast(){shapes_.pop_back();}

    ShapeTree(const int index) : index_{index}{}
    ShapeTree(const int index, std::vector<Shape*>& shapes) : index_{index}, shapes_{std::move(shapes)}{}};
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i achieve the same result using `unique_ptr`?

Comment: In `add`: `std::make_unique` is for creating a new object. You already created the object using `new`, so you should use `std::unique_ptr<Shape>(shape)`. You should consider to avoid `new` altogether - `makeChild` can return a `std::unique_ptr` via `std::make_unique`.

Comment: Change makeChild to return a unique_ptr to base, `std::unique_ptr<Shape> makeChild` and creating a child should not be done by new but with. `std::make_unique<Quad>` (and Rectangle etc). Then you need to use `push_back(std::move(shape))` to transfer onwership of the shape to the container (where shape is a std::unique_ptr<Shape>). When the container is removed so are all the shapes pointed to.

Comment: If possible I would consider making `Shape* makeChild(Type type) const` return a `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` so you are protecting the memory at all times. Like `std::unique_ptr<Shape> makeChild(Type type) const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is this line:

```
void add(Shape* shape) {shapes_.push_back(std::make_unique<Shape>(shape));}
```

`std::make_unique` is used to create a new object to be managed by the `unique_ptr`.
In your case you already allocated your object with `new`, and therefore you should simply use the `std::unique_ptr` constructor.

An immediate solution would be:

```
//----------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-----------------
void add(Shape* shape) {shapes_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Shape>(shape));}
```

---

**However:**
A better solution will avoid using `new` altogether.
`makeChild` can return a `std::unique_ptr` which can be `move`d into the `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Shape {};
struct Rectangle : public Shape {};
// ... all the derived Shapes

std::unique_ptr<Shape> makeChild()
{
    // Here you can create a std::unique_ptr to any derive from Shape based on a `Type` parameter you can add:
    return std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
}

struct ShapeTree {
    int index_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes_;

    //---------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvv------
    void add(std::unique_ptr<Shape> shape) { shapes_.push_back(std::move(shape)); }
    void removeLast() { shapes_.pop_back(); }

    // ...
};

int main()
{
    ShapeTree  st{ 333 };
    st.add(makeChild());
}
```

Comment: Thanks all!! Overall it was an error on my side. I was confused by the std::make_unique vs std::unique_ptr syntax. I've changed the factory method to return the unique_ptr and it now works like a charm, my only question is, should I now delete copy constructor and assignment operator for Shape or it is deleted by default?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You also haven't shown us `Shape`. Maybe you can consider to post it as a new question with all the relevant details (a post in StackOverflow should generally be limited to one issue).